# php includes is there any way to include a file relative only to that document?

Tags: php, include

If I have an index.php file that includes inc/footer.php I would write:

```
include 'inc/footer.php';
```

If I want to include another file inside footer.php, I must do it relative to the index.php file (the one that is including it). This may not be a problem, but what about if I want to include index.php from an entire different location?

I understand that there are several methods to achieve this like defining an absolute path or using `dirname(__FILE__)`.

This is something that has never been a real problem since one way or another I always figured it out but that I always wondered how exactly includes work in php.

Can someone explain me exaclty what is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This may help: (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Files for including are first looked
> for in each include_path entry
> relative to the current working
> directory, and then in the directory
> of current script. E.g. if your
> include_path is libraries, current
> working directory is /www/, you
> included include/a.php and there is
> include "b.php"  in that file, b.php
> is first looked in /www/libraries/
> and then in /www/include/. If filename
> begins with ./ or ../, it is looked
> for only in the current working
> directory or parent of the current
> working directory, respectively

Your question states:

> If I want to include another file
> inside footer.php, I must do it
> relative to the index.php file (the
> one that is including it).

This is true only if the filepath you are trying to `include()` starts with `./` or `../` . If you need to include a file above the current file using a relative path, you can (as you suggested) use:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../file.php';
```

---

If you define an absolute path, you can also add this to the current include_path:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/absolute/path');
```

You can then do all your includes relative to '/absolute/path/'.

Answer (score -4):

The best place to find the answer is in the PHP manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Short answer: 
the path is relative to the executing PHP script no the sub includes.

Setting a global absolute path to your functions, classes etc folders is the best method.

Comment: Is it bette to set it with a define or changin the ini file?

Comment: I mean set it as a define.

e.g. 
   define ('CLASS_DIR', '/path/to/classes/');