# call header from subfolder

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to call my header.php from project_1.php. That means that I have to go back to my root. I tried with the following, but there is no CSS is called:

```
<?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
```

The page is in:

> root -> projects -> project_1.php

The header is in:

> root -> resources -> includes -> header.php

When I call my header from a page there is in:

> root -> index.php

the header is working fine. Does anybody knows how I can solve that?

**Update after answers:**
Thank you for all the answers. I have tried the following, but with no result.

The path to the page is:

> http://localhost:8888/test/projects/portfolio_single.php

The header is in:

> http://localhost:8888/test/resources/includes/header.php

```
<?php include 'resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include '../../resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'../resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'../../resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/includes/header.php' ); ?>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `../` works in includes.

Comment: You might be able to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which is a string set to the web root of the current website. Do you get an error when you try to access it?

Comment: This might be useful: [php includes is there any way to include a file relative only to that document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031481/php-includes-is-there-any-way-to-include-a-file-relative-only-to-that-document)

Comment: <?php include( $_SERVER['vouzalis'] . '/resources/includes/header.php' ); ?> remove vouzalis and replace with DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: Shoot sorry, I forgot to add that to my list. I also tried that, but still the same thing.

Comment: pardon me, header is called by no CSS is applied? or header is not included at all?

Comment: Header is not called at all. It is weird.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` only takes you to the webroot. So you need to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/header.php'`

Comment: Ah ok cool, thank you a lot. Now something is happening. The header is called now, but the CSS is not called. Could you have a hint on why that could be?

Comment: I will make a new question with that, but at least the header is called now :-) Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/includes/header.php' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I just updated my question. I tried what you wrote, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code
Each time you use "../" you go back once a folder back, so you go to root and then you can go to resources and the folders you need to go to.

include ../../resources/includes/header.php';

Comment: Yhank you a lot for your answer. I just updated my question with the things I tried. But it dosent work yet:-/